# After migrating from jasperreports 3.6.0 to 4.5.1 JRFontNotFoundException occurs in some reports

Tags: fonts, jasper-reports, fill

we are about to migrate from jasperreports version 3.6.0 to the latest version 4.5.1. 
The compilation of our reports went well. 
But filling certain reports results in an JRFontNotFoundException

java.lang.RuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRFontNotFoundException: Font 'sansserif' is not available to the JVM. See the Javadoc for more details.

The weird thing about that is, that this exception is thrown just in a subset of 
all reports. There are working reports in the same project, which are also using sansserif mentioned above. I cannot figure out why this exception is

Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the solution to the problem - it was a casing problem, caused 
by an old version of iReport.

By looking at the exception above, I noticed that the term "sansserif" is completely written in lower case characters.

In the xml of the respective reports I found a mixture of "sansserif" and "SansSerif". 
We also migrated from iReport 3.6.0 to iReport 4.5.1. 
Nobody in our team is writing reports directly in XML. Therefore I guess that it is some 
kind of iReport problem.